# Giving a discount to every 10th customer if a method receives buy requests from concurrent clients

Tags: java, rmi

I'm writing a simple distributed program. The buy method serves concurrent clients using RMI.
I want to give a discount to every 10th customer. Ordering of buy requests is based on their time stamps to choose the 10th customer.
What is the best way to implement the buy method.

Comment: don't use timestamps. if this becomes a popular system, you WILL get collisions. use some other means of counting users.

Comment: Actually I want to get ideas about counting in the buy method! having a queue which is accessed by all instances ?

Comment: @MarcB If the collisions are random, does it matter??

Comment: @esmaeilnourani Given "every 10th customer" is an arbitary number how accurate does this need to be.  Can it be every 10th request per instance?

Comment: The main problem is that, this counting is global and not per instance.

Comment: @peter: consider multiple people hitting at the same timestamp, which happens to qualify for the discount. e.g. 4chan doing an organized 'break the bank' and getting a few thousand people doing a synchro-click.

Comment: There are k different front end server which assign every request a synchronized time stamp.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways you can do this. You could use the timestamp if it suficiently random, but you could also use.

```
static final AtomicInteger COUNTER = new AtomicInteger();

if (COUNTER.getAndIncrement() % EVERY_NTH_USER == 0) {
   // give offer
}
```

Comment: I have to sort the requests based on their timestamps.

Comment: I don't get how you can sort requests in the midst of processing them.

Comment: The time stamps are used to determine an ordering of buy
requests and every 10th buy request is automatically given a discount

Comment: You don't "have to use timestamps". Give the discount as the requests come in, every 10th one, using Peter's code.

Comment: Because i assume that request may receive in a wrong order. I give every request a time stamp to determine the real 10th  request

Comment: What would happen if a different 1/10th of customers got the reward?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, is this a homework problem? You insist on using timestamps so that you don't give the discount to the wrong customer in case they are processed out of order. But "every 10th customer" sounds like a very arbitrary rule. Who cares if you go by when orders reach the server rather than when they are placed?

If we assume that it must be done by a timestamp assigned when the order is placed, but that the server that decides on the discounts won't necessarily receive the orders in order, then ... is there a known maximum delay before an order reaches the server, and can we wait at least that long before applying the discount? If not, the problem is unsolvable. If the server looks at the timestamps on the orders and determines that some order is number 10, how does it know that there is not another order, with a timestamp between number 9 and number 10, that is still in transit and has not yet arrived?

To determine "every 10th order", I think pretty much by definition there must be some central server that is counting the orders, so all orders must flow through this single server or at least "register" with this single server. Therefore the logical way to count is to count the orders as they arrive.

Can we reject orders that arrive after some maximum wait time? Or if, for example, 90% of the time orders will arrive within 3 seconds, can we say that if an order doesn't arrive within 3 seconds that we accept that we might not meet a strict every-tenth-order rule? If the answers are no, then the problem is impossible.

If the definition of the problem is that it must be done based on timestamps assigned by independent concurrent servers, then the only way I see that it could be done is to have a known maximum time that it can take for an order to reach the central server from the satellite server. Then sort the orders by timestamp and count ten after the last discount was awarded. If the timestamp on that order is less than maxium-wait-time ago, then we must wait before deciding if we can award the discount. Then go back and try the process over again, this time including any new orders that have arrived since the last try. Something like:

```
(pseudo-code)
loop forever
  select order_id, timestamp from orders where prcoessed=0 order by timestamp
  count to tenth record
  if timestamp<now-max_wait then
    award discount to number 10
    mark numbers 1 to 10 as processed
  else
    do nothing
  endif
endloop
```

Specifically, given the timestamp rule it is not possible to award the discount the instant you receive the order, because you have no way to know that there is not another order on its way with an earlier timestamp.

We'd have to make some decision about what to do with orders that arrive after the maximum wait time, whether they are rejected, allowed to process when they arrive, etc.

If you expect to notify the customer at the time they place the order that they are receiving the discount, that isn't possible because you don't know. Well, if the max wait time is short enough, like not more than a couple of seconds, you may be able to hold off on responding to the customer until the time has elapsed. If the maximum wait is minutes, I don't think you could stall a response that long. But I guess that depends on other requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I clarify my question:  There are replicated front end servers with different clocks and they give every request a synchronized time stamp (using Berkeley clock synchronization algorithm) and send this request to buy server on different machine! The concern is ordering the requests which are received at frontend servers (with different clock times) and this total ordering happens at buy server. Order of receiving request at frontend servers is important not the real order they are sent.

Comment: Why is it the order that they hit front-end that is important, not the order they hit the buy server? It's a pretty arbitrary judgement for no real reason.

Besides, even with clock sync there will be random differences - time synchronization is best effort.

Comment: Actually users only have access to front-end servers and these server send requests to buy server.

Comment: Yes I realise that - why is it important that the front-end server timings are maintained?

Comment: I do time sync by giving every front-end server a time offset, then every server use this offset to timestamp request and sends it to buy server, where total ordering take place.

Comment: I still have to say, So what? So we have some central server X and several front-end servers, say A, B, and C. Suppose a customer hits A 1/10 of a second before some other customer hits B, but the order from B makes it to X first, and we give the order from B the discount. This is "wrong" by the timestamp rule. Why does it matter? Implementing a server-sequence rule is easy. Implementing a timestamp rule is hard. Is there a reason to do it the hard way, or did someone just decide "this is the rule" without thinking through the implications?